Macro: void value not ignored as it ought to be
I'm trying to make a simple assertion macro that returns a boolean, but I keep getting a void function.
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE

#define CASSERT(predicate) \
 ({ \
    if((predicate)) \
    { \
        (TRUE); \
    }else\
    { \
        __debugbreak(); \
       (FALSE); \
    }})

I want to use it like this
if(!CASSERT(X==Y)){}

this is the error I get
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

error: could not convert '<statement>' from 'void' to 'bool'

I tried a few variations of this code and none of them seems to be working! the output of the CASSERT is a void function!

Rather than { if (predicate) ... else ...}, perhaps (predicate) ? ... : ...?

In new use code use stdbool.h instead of homebrew booleans.   Is there a reason why you want !TRUE and !!FALSE?  Consider  inverting the meaning of  the predicate or swap the two expresisons of the conditional operator.

If you are trying to use GCC's statement expressions (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) then you syntax is not correct - the variable with resulting value must be the last in the code block

@qrdl Yes,I can confirm, making it in the last block works too
if(!(predicate)) { __debugbreak(); } (predicate);
Thanks

@ma1169 It would be better to use a local variable in the statement expression so that the predicate macro parameter is expanded only once. E.g. #define CASSERT(predicate) ({ int result__ = (predicate) ? TRUE : FALSE; if (!result__) { __debugbreak(); } result__; }).

GCC's statement expressions extension requires that the last statement in the block is an expression statement.  Here it is an if statement, so that doesn't work.

Perform the text replacement yourself.
if(!CASSERT(X==Y)){}

Becomes:
if(!{
    if((X==Y)) {
        (!0);
    }
    else {
        __debugbreak();
        (0);
    }}) {}

Does that look like valid C code? It isn't, because a conditional statement is not an expression returning a boolean.
You may wish to use a conditional expression with the comma operator to sequence the __debugbreak() and FALSE. Something like:
#define CASSERT(PRED) ((PRED) ? TRUE : (__debugbreak(), FALSE))

Your code would now expand to:
if(!((X==Y) ? !0 : (__debugbreak(), 1))) {}

That is valid C code.

I think the original actually expands to if (!({ if((X==Y)) { {!0; } else { __debugbreak(); 0; }})), which uses the GCC "statement expression" extension ({ … }) where the last statement in the block can yield a value. The trouble is that the original code's statement expression does not contain a last statement that yields a value.
